how to write SpyOn()
let compoent = MockComponent;

it('should be called the your Component', () =\>{

component.yourComponent() // first called your component

spyOn(component, 'method').and.returnValue('expeted data')

})

spyon is observe the component

First create the spy, then execute the method, then finally evaluate it!
let component = MockComponent;

it('should be called the your Component', () =>{
    spyOn(component, 'method').and.returnValue('expeted data')
    component.yourComponent() // first called your component
    expect(component.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
})

